# Write Contents in a text file in a tabular order using C#

Tags: c#, performance, tabular, writefile

I want to write contents into a text file from a DatagridView in my application. In my text file, I would like to follow a format like

```
Column1            Column2              Column3
[Cell1]            [Cell2]              [Cell3]
[Cell1]            [Cell2]              [Cell3]
[Cell1]            [Cell2]              [Cell3]
```

and so on in a tabular format. How do I **efficiently** do that as you see I'm bothered about the locations of text as well to bring about a tabular format in a text file (in Notepad).

Should I use char[] but I feel it might not be efficient. 
Pl guide with an efficient solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot write a complete solution here, but this is your starting point
[Formatting Types on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy.aspx),
in particular the paragraph regarding Composite Formatting

The key is string.Format with columns lenght specifiers like

```
string.Format("{0:D15}{1:D20}", rowColumn1, rowColumn2);
```

Comment: FormatSpecifiers are very useful... Thanks!

Comment: As a side note, remember that showing or printing your text file without a fixed width font, will result in columns not well aligned

Answer (score 0):

Here `datagridview` is the DataGirdView where all the data is present

```
C:\File.txt
```

is the file where all the data is stored.

```
      string data = String.Empty;
      for (int col = 0; col < datagridview.ColumnCount; col++)
      {
          data += Convert.ToString(datagridview.Columns[col].HeaderText);
      }
      data += "\n";
      for (int i = 0; i < datagridview.RowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < datagridview.ColumnCount; j++)
            {
                data += Convert.ToString(datagridview.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
                data += "\t";
            }
            data += "\n";
        }
        StreamWriter SW;
        SW = File.AppendText(@"C:\File.txt");

        SW.WriteLine(data + Environment.NewLine);
        SW.Close();
```

Comment: This is not an Efficient solution I was expecting.